# managing text overflow with CSS

Tags: css, position, overflow

I am trying to visualize a sort of TV program guide, a line for each channel. The HTML structure is:

```
<DIV id="channel2_new" class="channel"> // id different for each channel
  <IMG src="channel2.png">              // logo source different for each channel
  <DIV class=program">
    <P style="width:200">               // actual width value reflects program length
      <SPAN class="time">06:00</SPAN>   // actual time
      <SPAN class="title">TG2</SPAN>    // actual title
    </P>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

The CSS is:

```
.time{
    visibility:hidden; width:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; 
    }

.channel{
    height:30px; white-space:nowrap; margin:0px; width:1000px; overflow:hidden;
    }

.logo{
    border:none; float:left; height:20px; margin-top:5px; 
    }

.program{
    position:absolute; left:80px; 
    }

P{
    float:left; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; height:20px; overflow:hidden; margin-top:0px; 
    }
```

The idea is to show only the programs that fit within the "channel" width (corresponding to a specified time window, i.e., from 6pm to 10pm). For the programs that start within this window (i.e., at 9pm) but end later (i.e., 11pm), only a partial box should be shown (this is what I hope the "overflow:hidden" attributes should do).
See this example web site to understand better what I'm trying to do: http://it.tv.yahoo.com/

In my case, this happens only in an apparently random way: for some channels it works, for other channels the last "program" rectangle is completely missing (no border, no text). If I change the window width, the same channel that was showing correctly might not be working any more, while others might work!

Do you havee any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion #1. Post a full example, with more complete HTML and CSS.  http://jsfiddle.net/ is pretty good for this :)

Comment: OK, I'll do it, later. I didn't know jsfiddle ... looks interesting, but I'll need some time to start using it. Thanks

Comment: Here is the full code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bobit/P8V4e/5/). Logos don't show up because I don't know how to attach external files to jsfiddle. However, you can see that the 6th and 14th channels work well, the others don't. If you play with the value "1000" in the CSS (.channel:width) you can see different behaviours. For instance, change it to 700 and you'll see that channels 1 to 7, 9 and 16 work.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is `text-overflow: ellipsis;` if you apply it to your `p` like I've done here: **http://jsfiddle.net/P8V4e/6/** you get the ellipsis when the text from `.title` overflows the `p` element. Is this the behavior you're looking for?

I also added a `min-width: 1em;` property to the `p`, that way it won't collapse completely and not show the ellipsis, but will still retain the width of the other elements. I don't know if that will mess up your formatting.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but it will actually not solve my problem. Trying to explaining it better: for some channels, it seems that programs end at some time in the middle of the window, as if there was no other program after that time. Actually, there are other programs, but they are not shown (I guess, because the entire <P> tag doesn't fit in the available space. However, for some other channels, the <P> tag content is shown, and just truncated at the end (the behaviour that I would like to obtain)